# How to get CSS % unit to represent height instead of width

Tags: html, css, css-animations, dropdown, margin

I'm trying to make an animated dropdown/expandable component with CSS. I currently have an expanded and collapsed class, implemented as follows:

```css
.expanded {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.collapsed {
  margin-top: -100%;
}
```

However, when I actually assign these classes according to the current dropdown state, it seems like `-100%` is equivalent to `-100%` of my element's **width**, not height like I want it to. This means the dropdown doesn't get fully collapsed when my element height is more than the width. Is there any way to change which dimension the `%` unit references?

If not, what would be a better way to animate the expanding/collapsing of a container?

Image of the computed sizes of my collapsed element (with `margin-top: -100%`):
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Re: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin#values `<percentage>` "The size of the margin as a percentage, relative to the inline size (width in a horizontal language, defined by `writing-mode`) of the containing block."

Answer (score 0):

The way you are going about it is a little odd. I'd either use the standard max-height way. Or the best way, grid.

```
.dropdown {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 0.5s ease-out;
}

 .expanded {
    max-height: 500px; 
}
```

This method is straightforward but has a limitation; you need to know or estimate the maximum height your content will need.

For a more dynamic, neater solution, use grid-template-rows

```
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 0fr auto;
    transition: grid-template-rows 0.5s ease-out;    
}

.container.expanded {
    grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
}
```